# What are all of Minecraft's /give NBT tags?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know all possible NBT tags for `/give`:

```
give @p minecraft:example{NBT}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this question isn't answerable in a way that you can understand. There are so many tags that we can't possibly provide a full list. You can check out the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Player.dat_format) for item structure.

Answer (score 2):

Item data tags are a recursive (tree) structure of JSON data associated with an item. Doing a quick calculation, I estimate there are about:

### 7.9 * 10<sup>61093</sup> ≈ 10<sup>10<sup>4.786</sup></sup>

Technically there are a very large number of possible item tags, too many to be able to list. Just estimating how many there are: I only consider books, which contain their text within such tags, and thus their number will dwarf everything else. When dealing with big numbers like these adding a smaller number to a big number: `B + s ~ B`, so we only consider the most numerous category (as it's likely orders of magnitude more numerous than any other).  Question: *How many books are there?*

A book can have 50 pages, 256 characters per page, and all characters must be in the BMP. There are currently 55,503 characters assigned in it.

This means you can have `55,503 ^ 50 ^256`. This is approximately 1.8 * 10<sup>60727</sup> distinct books.

Each such book can then be [enchanted](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Summary_of_enchantments) in various ways. Approximately `2^9 * 256 ^ 13 * (2 ^ 63) ^ 4 * 2 ^32 * 6 * 11 * 21 * 128 * 6 * 128 * 15 * 11 * 8 * 4` ways, or about 2.3 * 10 <sup>131</sup>.

There are 4 book states.

The title of the book and author name are another 32 * 55,503 options.

There are 2 ^ 24 = 16777216 colours.

There are 128 hide states.

There are attributes which take [double-precision fp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (52-bit mantissa) values. This gives another `PROD(2 ^ 52 * N)` multiplier for each for: `(10 * 2 ^ 52)^3 * (11 * 2 ^ 52)^3 * (2 ^ 52)^2 * 2log(30)* 2 ^ 52 * 2log(20) * 2 ^ 52 * 2log(5) * 2 ^ 52` possibilities or about 1.0 * 10<sup>180</sup>.

There's two 64-bit INTs for customModelData and damage, two booleans for another 2<sup>128</sup> options.

Multiply everything to get the number above...

A list of all the possible valid tags in the vanilla game can be found at https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure.

Comment: Not to mention that item data supports user-defined NBT too, so the possibilities are endless.